# Как мы фоновую речь песни оформляем на письме?

Tags: оформление-текста

Как мы фоновую речь песни оформляем на письме? В скобках? Это фрагмент из песни «День, который жду» Боярского.

> Наверное рок мой тебя вспоминать вновь. / Прикосновенье губ твоих — словно ожог. / Тепло голубых глаз я в зимнюю ночь спас, / А удержать тебя не смог **(увы не смог)**.

> Наверное рок мой тебя вспоминать вновь. / Прикосновенье губ твоих — словно ожог. / Тепло голубых глаз я в зимнюю ночь спас, / А удержать тебя не смог, **увы не смог**.

> Наверное рок мой тебя вспоминать вновь. / Прикосновенье губ твоих — словно ожог. / Тепло голубых глаз я в зимнюю ночь спас, / А удержать тебя не смог **(Увы не смог)**.

> Наверное рок мой тебя вспоминать вновь. / Прикосновенье губ твоих — словно ожог. / Тепло голубых глаз я в зимнюю ночь спас, / А удержать тебя не смог. **(Увы не смог.)**

Comment: Правильно: на письме. Вы можете объяснить орфограмму? Или вам помочь?

Comment: Я просто не заметил мягкий знак. Спасибо.

Comment: Будьте внимательны, сэр. Ведь и вы у нас в центре внимания)

Comment: Леопольд: «_**Я просто не заметил мягкий знак**_». === В названии темы тоже не заметили? 

Comment: Лео, серьезно? _ПесЬни_? _На пиСМе_? Мягкий знак поставили не в том месте, так еще и междометие в выделенных скобках не обособили.

Comment: А песьню кто исправлять будет?  Пушкин?  Намеренное искажение орфографии?  В принятом ответе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем тексте пропущено несколько запятых.

В описанном вами случая хватит как многоточия, так и дефиса, и скобок. И просто нового предложения.

Нет никакого строгого правила на этот случай, потому что ни в одном из случаев не будет ошибки.

Даю корректный, по моему мнению, вариант:

> Наверное, рок мой — тебя вспоминать вновь.
> Прикосновение губ твоих — словно ожог.
> Тепло голубых глаз я в зимнюю ночь спас,
> А удержать тебя не смог — увы, не смог.

Что касается вашего вопроса о том, где искать тексты песен с корректной пунктуацией, то вы такого источника не найдёте. Дело в том, что часто сам источник текстов — их авторы — сами пишут с ошибками. Некоторые даже с ужасными. Например, группа "Князь": "Оденьте на ноги мои стальные сапоги" — вместо "наденьте", группа "Король и Шут": "Был грязный плащ на нём одет" — вместо "надет".

Потом эти песни попадают на форумы с разборами аккордов, которые часто делают фанаты, которые, может, хорошо разбираются в нотах, но это не обязывает их быть грамотными людьми.

Поэтому корректность текста всегда нужно определять самостоятельно.

Comment: Можете подкорригировать этот текст? Я не понимаю, где эти знаки ставить. Чей это вообще текст? Где искать тексты песен, написанные уже с корректной пунктуацией?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр по вашей просьбе дополнил ответ